# Add list as row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a multiple lists as:-

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [3,4,5,5,7]
C = [6,54,3,2,8,9,9]
D = [3,2,54,33,45,55,5]
.........so on
```

All I want to append this list as row into pandas dataframe `df` as column `digits`-
Something as,

```
print (df)

digits
[1,2,3,4,5]
[3,4,5,5,7]
[6,54,3,2,8,9,9]
[3,2,54,33,45,55,5]
.............
............
```

Comment: check edited question

Comment: Why would you want to do that instead of having a nested list? Pandas is not designed for columns containing lists, it works mostly with scalar values. You lose all the benefit by doing that